# Model validation with separate dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Apologies, quite new to sklearn. I'm trying to validate a model using an external dataset for binary classification of text strings. I've trained the model but want to use it against another dataset of a different size for prediction rather than include the data in the initial dataset split. Is this even possible?

Initial split

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0, analyzer="char", sublinear_tf=True, ngram_range=(3, 3))
Xprod = vectorizer.fit_transform(prod_good)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(total_requests)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=21)
```

Test the model

```
linear_svm=LinearSVC(C=1)
linear_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = linear_svm.predict(X_test)
score_test = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

New prediction

```
newpred = linear_svm.predict(Xprod)
...
Error:
ValueError: X has 4553 features per sample; expecting 24422
```

Think I'm misunderstanding some basic concepts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fit_transform` makes a `fit` and then a `transform`. So this line fits your vectorizer and then transforms `total_requests` to `X`:

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(total_requests)
```

As your vectorizer must be fitted only one time (in order to have the same matrix of features each time you use your vectorizer), to compute `Xprod`, you just need to use `transform`:

```
Xprod = vectorizer.transform(prod_good)
```

Also, you need to compute Xprod after the vectorizer is fitted, so compute Xprod after X.

Comment: Thanks, after some fiddling I came to the same conclusion. Much appreciated